# Creating Intents with putExtra

Tags: android, android-intent

I have been creating Intents using putExtra() for quite a while now and just read in the Android documentation that I should be prefixing the 'name' with the package name.  So, instead of 'putExtra( "ButtonText", "Ok")' it should be more like 'putExtra( "com.mycompany.myapplication.ButtonText", "Ok" ).

Is this really necessary? (seems to be OK without it).

If it is necessary what is the advantage?

Also, is the package name the callers or the one being called?  If it is the callers the 'called Activity' has to know about the callers name which wouldn't be very generic.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this really necessary? (seems to be OK without it).

No, it isn't *necessary* for a completely stand-alone app but may be considered to be good practice anyway.

It is more important in apps which are publicly available so they can interact but maintain some way of uniquely identifying themselves and the data they're exchanging. As for which package name is used will depend on the context.

To give an abstract example...

Company A produces an app which can provide some sort of data processing which apps produced by Company B and Company C can use. The 'action' for the intent will be named relevant to Company A but the data passed into it by the two 'client' apps will be named relevant to the client apps companies. Example...

AppA's docs...

```
To request data processing use:
com.companyA.intent.action.PROCESS_DATA

Pass data with the above intent as an extra named:
<your package name>.SOME_DATA
```

Now when the relevant component of AppA is called with the above, it will check that there's an 'extra' with a name which ends with .SOME_DATA but it will also be able to maintain that data separately from other data provided by other apps due to the unique prefix. So...

Company B code

```
Intent i = new Intent(com.companyA.intent.action.PROCESS_DATA);
i.putExtra(com.companyB.SomeApp.SOME_DATA, data);
```

Company C code

```
Intent i = new Intent(com.companyA.intent.action.PROCESS_DATA);
i.putExtra(com.companyC.SomeOtherApp.SOME_DATA, data);
```

OK, possibly not one of my better examples but what it comes down to is it's important to see how the Android environment is very much about different application components being able to use each other, pass data and for the source of that data to be uniquely identifiable.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up a lot.  There is a small point I don't get in your example.  - Is it assumed that the "com.companyB.SomeApp.SOME_DATA" is any particular type (e.g. String)?  I would assume it is a string and Company A's code has to trim off everything before and including the last 'dot'?  If so, this would have to be 'understood' by Company A, B and C (obviously).

Comment: @steve: putExtra uses the form (String name, <type> value) where 'name' must be understood on both sides - 'value' can be different types (int, string and so on). My example was based on how apps can communicate directly rather than in a broadcast (such as "I have an image file here, who knows how to open it?" kind of Intent). Passing data between your own application components still means that they need to know what the 'extra' means but there's always the potential for developers to create apps that other developers can use based on published docs

Comment: Thanks @MisterSquonk, I understand.  I think a good pattern for this kind of thing would be to always pass a bundle over in the 'extras' with a fully qualified 'name'.  Then, the individual values in the bundle could have short names as it would be clear who the caller was based on the bundle's name.  This would be easier to parse and also read in the code.  Of course you could qualify every piece of data but that seems a bit like overkill to me...  Thanks again (and thanks to the other commenters as well)

Comment: Great write up. Thank for that. I'm still curious, though, what is the main benefit of uniquely identifying where the "extra" intent data came from? Wouldn't AppA deal with the request the same way and provide it back to the requester? I.e. How would knowing it came from `com.companyB.SomeApp` vs `com.companyC.SomeOtherApp` be used? Thanks!

Comment: @JoshPinter : By supplying a package and app name such as com.CompanyB.SomeApp it would be possible for the CompanyA app to use PackageManager to identify any exported Services (for example) and other components which might be used to receive results from the CompanyA app. Alternatively consider a BroadcastReceiver (for example) which is registered for an explicit `<intent-filter>` such as `ACTION_VIEW` - there could be many apps 'listening' for the same action and being able to filter an Intent extra by its package / app name is useful.

Comment: @Squonk Okay, that makes sense. Do you think if you're not implementing those types of scenarios and are not checking the Package Name, would it be permissible to not include it?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds more like a "best practices" thing than an actual requirement.  The benefit you get here is if you stuff a lot of things in generic intents that are handled by several activities spanning several applications, then you're being more specific about the data in your Intent.  If you're using these intents only internally in your application and only your own activities are handling them, you're fine the way you are.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a GREAT idea IF you are wrapping your extended data into a serializable class say com.mycompany.myapp.MyAppData and sending it as:

```
intent.putExtra("com.mycompany.myapp.MyAppData",myAppData); //==> out
```

and retrieving it as:

```
MyAppData myAppData= (com.mycompany.myapp.MyAppData)intent.getSerializableExtra("com.mycompany.myapp.MyAppData",myAppData; // <== in
```

JAL